# Error saving Item in cakephp when I upload an image within that item

Tags: cakephp

I am working in cakephp for the first time. I was able to get started with a Product model that has an image variable. I am able to upload the image but then I am not able to save to product afterwards. This is my add.ctp

```
<div class="products form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Product', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Product'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('slug');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
        echo $this->Form->input('price');
        echo $this->Form->input('weight');

            //upload image    
            echo $this->Form->input('Product.image', array('type'=>'file', 'tmp_name'=>'temp'));



    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>

        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Products'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my ProductsController add() funciton

```
 public function add($seller_id = null) {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Product->create();
            debug($this->request->data);
                            if(isset($this->request->data["Product"]["image"]["name"]))
                            {
                                $file = new File($this->request->data["Product"]["image"]["name"]);
                                debug($this->request->data);
                                $ext = pathinfo(($this->request->data["Product"]["image"]["name"]), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                                if ($ext != 'jpg' && $ext != 'jpeg' && $ext != 'gif' && $ext != 'png') 
                                {
                                    $this->Session->setFlash('You may only upload image files.');
                                }else
                                {
                                    if(move_uploaded_file($this->request->data["Product"]["image"]["tmp_name"],WWW_ROOT."/img/uploads/" . $this->data["Product"]["image"]["name"]) == true)
                                    {
                                        $this->data["Product"]["image"] =  $this->data["Image"]["image"]["name"];
                                    }
                                }
                                if ($this->Product->save($this->request->data)) //error here
                                {
                                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The product has been saved'));
                                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                                    $this->request->data['Product']['seller_id'] = $seller_id;
                                }
                                else {
                                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }

                        }$this->Session->setFlash(__('The image could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }

    }
```

Can anyone see why it would upload and move the image but not save the Product?
Also, here is what is produced from  debug($this->request->data);

```
array(
    'Product' => array(
        'name' => '8',
        'slug' => '8',
        'description' => '8',
        'price' => '8',
        'weight' => '8',
        'image' => array(
            'name' => 'celeb16.com-purple-strapless-short-bridesmaid-dress-g129-33(1).jpg',
            'type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'tmp_name' => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpDD08.tmp',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 1404
        )
    )
)
```

one more piece of information that might be helpful is that when I use this code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Product', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>
```

it will allow the image to properly upload but will not save the product and when I use this code:

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Product'); ?>
```

it will save the product but not upload the image

Comment: Can you elaborate on `//error here`? What error or message are getting, is it just not saving?

Comment: Also what version of Cake are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
$this->data["Product"]["image"] =  $this->data["Image"]["image"]["name"];
```

to this:

```
$this->request->data["Product"]["image"] =  $this->request->data["Image"]["image"]["name"];
```

In your original code you're trying to manipulate `$this->data`, and in your save call you're referencing `$this->request->data`:

```
$this->Product->save($this->request->data)
```

Hopefully that should fix things up, it's hard to tell without the error itself :)

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

you need to save the data before you do the moving of the image, try this..

```
 if ($this->Product->save($this->request->data)) //error here
                            {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The product has been saved'));
                                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                                $this->request->data['Product']['seller_id'] = $seller_id;
                            }
  if(move_uploaded_file($this->request->data["Product"]["image"]["tmp_name"],WWW_ROOT."/img/uploads/" . $this->data["Product"]["image"]["name"]) == true)
                                {
                                    $this->data["Product"]["image"] =  $this->data["Image"]["image"]["name"];
                                }
                            }
```

Hope it works for you

Heres an example of how I've previously achieved a file upload, try using it as a guideline I suggest keeping it simple, also if you want to limit file types I suggest doing this in the MODEL.

```
public function add() {

 if($this->request->is('post')){

 $file = $this->request->data['Upload']['file'];
 if($this->Upload->save($this->data) && move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],APP.'webroot/files/uploads'.DS.$this->Upload->id.'.mp4')) 
 {
 $this->Session->setFlash('<p class="uploadflash">The upload has been saved</p>', true);
 $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Uploads', 'action' => 'watch', $this->Upload->id));
 }  else {
 $this->Session->setFlash('<p class="loginerror">The upload could not be saved, mp4 files can be saved only.</p>', true);   
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: I have tried every order I could think of. I can either save the product or the image. Never both.

Comment: Try doing this `if($this->Product->save($this->request->data) && move_uploaded_file($this->request->data["Product"]["image"]["tmp_name"],WWW_ROOT."/img/uploads/" . $this->data["Product"]["image"]["name"]) == true))`

Comment: ive added a file upload that I've previously used in the above comment, hope that helps